# Multiple compound unique constraints over same column

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity with two unique constraints over same column:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="checklist_item", schema = "general",       
        uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(name = "uq_general_checklist_ordinal",
                             columnNames = {"checklist_id", "ordinal"}),                             
                             @UniqueConstraint(name = "uq_general_checklist_ordinal",
                                     columnNames = {"checklist_id", "name"})                           
                             }
      )
public class ChecklistItem extends RecordInfo {

    @NotNull
    @Column
    @Length(max = 30)
    private String name;

    @Column
    @NotNull
    private long ordinal;

    @Column
    private String comment;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE)
    @JoinColumn(name="checklist_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_general_checklist_checklistitem"))
    private Checklist checklist;
```

I am trying to make two separate unique constraint combinations:[(checklist_id, name), (checklist_id, ordinal), but hibernate makes one combined unique constraint as I can see in logs:

`Hibernate: alter table general.checklist_item add constraint uq_general_checklist_ordinal unique (checklist_id, ordinal, name)`

Hibernate version is `5.4.6.Final`

As these two thing are not equivalent, what is the proper way to achieve creating two separate compound unique constraints over the same column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `@UniqueConstraint` name is repeated.